# Interactive R script on Binder does not work. **Kernel not found**

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, binders

I am new to data science and code sharing.
I am trying to share my R codes with my team. I have created a jupyter notebook, created a github repository, then upload my notebook to Binders.
My script in Binders is interactive, however, it runs as python code and not R code.
there are a few steps that I was not too sure that might mess this up.
1- for the requremnt.txt file, I had to manually type the package name with their version. I would love it if someone tells me what is the right way to create requirement file for R script
2-In the repository creation on github I didn't know what I had to pick for "Add.fitignore" or "Add a license" so I left them to "None"

when I open my notebook in Binders, it gives me an error  **Kernel not found**.

What am I doing wrong? Please help

I have installed R on jupyternote book, and it works fine when I open the notebook using Anaconda.